# Bluebird Promise.map is not working

Tags: javascript, dictionary, promise, sequelize.js, bluebird

I am trying to build associations between a question and answers. And I am using to use Bluebird's API `.map` to make sure a redirect only happens after all the `question.addAnswers(answer)` promises are done. Therefore, in my terminal, I should see something like this:

```
done adding a answer to the question
done adding a answer to the question
finished
```

However, what I see is:

```
finished
done adding a answer to the question
done adding a answer to the question
```

Therefore, I assume the `Promise.map` is not working at all. Did I miss something? How can I make it work?

Here is my code:

```
router.post('/create', function(req, res) {
  models.Question.create({
    content: req.body.question
  })
  .then(function(question) {
    if (!question) {
      res.render('questions/new', {
          error: "Question \"#{req.body.question}\" fails to be created"
        });
    } else {
      // Update the new question to each user
      models.User.findAll()
      .then(function(users) {
        users.forEach(function(user) {
          user.addQuestion(question)
        });
      });
      Promise.map(req.body.answers, function(answer){
        return createAndAddToQuestion(question, answer, res)
      })
      .then(function(){
        console.log('finished')
        res.redirect("/questions/success/?question_id=" + question.id);
      });
    };
  })
})

var createAndAddToQuestion = function(question, answer, res) {
  models.Answer.create({
    content: answer
  })
  .then(function(ans) {
    if (ans) {
      var promise = question.addAnswer(ans)
      promise.then(function(){
        console.log("done adding a answer to the question")
      });
      return question.addAnswer(ans);
    } else {
      res.render('questions/new', {
        error: "Answer \"#{answer}\" fails to be created"
      });
    };
  });
}
```

*UPDATE*
I just update the `createAndAddToQuestion`, so it will return a promise instead. Outcome stays the same. `Promise.map` is not working.

```
var createAndAddToQuestion = function(question, answer, res) {
  models.Answer.create({
    content: answer
  })
  .then(function(ans) {
    if (ans) {
      return question.addAnswer(ans).then(function() {
        console.log('done')
      })
    } else {
      res.render('questions/new', {
        error: "Answer \"#{answer}\" fails to be created"
      });
    };
  });
}
```

Comment: `createAndAddToQuestions` doesn't return anything, but presumably you want it to return a Promise of some sort. Maybe you just want `return models.Answer.create...`?

Comment: Also, you probably want `return promise` instead of `return question.addAnswer(ans)`... otherwise you're calling that function twice.

Comment: Thanks! That was a typo. I changed it back, but same outcome. @smarx

Comment: `createAndAddToQuestion` still doesn't return anything. As I said in my first comment, maybe you want `return models.Answer.create...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your most prominent problem is that `createAndAddToQuestion` does not return a promise, so `map` cannot know what to wait for.

Also you don't wait for `models.User.findAll`, call `question.addAnswer(ans);` twice, potentially try to render an error message multiple times if answers fail to be created, and do not have a generic error handler. You should be doing

```
router.post('/create', function(req, res) {
  createQuestion(req.body).then(function(question) {
    console.log('finished')
    res.redirect("/questions/success/?question_id=" + question.id);
  }, function(err) {
    res.render('questions/new', {
      error: err.message
    });
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500);
  });
});

function createQuestion(opts) {  
  return models.Question.create({
    content: opts.question
  })
  .then(function(question) {
    if (!question) {
      throw new Error("Question \"#{opts.question}\" fails to be created");
    }
    // Update the new question to each user
    return Promise.all([
      models.User.findAll()
      .then(function(users) {
        users.forEach(function(user) {
          user.addQuestion(question)
        })
      }),
      Promise.map(opts.answers, function(answer){
        return createAndAddToQuestion(question, answer)
      })
    ]).return(question);
  });
}

function createAndAddToQuestion(question, answer) {
  return models.Answer.create({
    content: answer
  })
  .then(function(ans) {
    if (!ans) {
      throw new Error("Answer \"#{answer}\" fails to be created");
    }
    return question.addAnswer(ans);
  })
  .then(function(){
    console.log("done adding a answer to the question")
  });
}
```

Comment: I tried it, an error is return: `Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'NaN' in 'where clause' `
Also, I didn't wait for `user.findAll()` intentionally because I don't need the result from that method when I redirect. Do I have to wait for it to finish although I don't need the result right away? This way, it can save some time. In that case, my original code should works, right?
In addition, in your code, how does the question get pass to the route from `createQuestion`?`question.addAnswer` will return question in its promise?

Comment: @WeiRoR: Thanks for the hints, updated my answer. I had indeed forgotten to return the `question` from the helper function. Where that database error comes from I don't know, but that it is an unhandled rejection does worry me. Regarding the findAll, I would still wait for it so that you can catch errors from its execution. You can carry it out in parallel to the other actions though.

Comment: That works. Thank you so much! Could you explain a little bit how the question got returned through `Promise.all([...]).return(question)`? Also, inside the route, where is `function(err) {...}` in `.then(...)` from? I thought there is usually only one function inside of  `.then(...)`.

Comment: @WeiRoR `Promise.all` just waits for the question to be added to the users, and the answers to be added to the question. Then, [`return`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/return.html) does what its name says. Regarding two callbacks, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24663315/1048572).

Comment: Thank you so much!